# Duplicate attribute error in AndroidMainfest.xml while adding a new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I was making a simple text field and 'send' button to display whatever the user typed in the text field. The program is completely illustrated in the Android training tutorials by android.com.

Whenever I'm adding the Activity `DisplayMessageActivity`, I'm getting "Duplicate attribute" as an error. Here's the code:

```
<application

      <activity android.name="DroidStart"/>
      <activity
       android:name="com.start.droidstart.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_droid" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Update:** I fixed the problems that were pointed out, but I'm still getting the error. Here's my current AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.start.droidstart"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
       android:name="DroidStart"
       android:name="com.start.droidstart.DisplayMessageActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_droid" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

The error looks like this

> Error parsing XML; duplicate attribute. type Android AAPT problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two errors:

1. Be sure to close your `<application>` tag.
2. Use `android:name`, not `android.name`.

So the first 3 lines should change from:

```
<application

      <activity android.name="DroidStart"/>
```

to

```
<application>

      <activity android:name="DroidStart"/>
```

**Update:**

In your updated code, you have:

```
  <activity
   android:name="DroidStart"
   android:name="com.start.droidstart.DisplayMessageActivity"
```

You are using `android:name` twice, which is why you are getting this error. You should probably change this to:

```
  <activity
   android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
```

assuming `DisplayMessageActivity` is the class name of the Activity you which to refer to.

Last, you forgot your `manifest` end tag: you should have `</manifest>` at the very end of your file.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my problem :D
I made the changes you suggested. But I still get the same error :(
Is there anything else that could go wrong?
i'm using this application tag now

<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: @AlfazAhmed That looks fine; it's strange that you're seeing the same error. Be sure to save the file, then clean your build environment and try the build again. If it still gives you the same error after that, then please update your question with your current AndroidManifest.xml and the exact error message. (You should add those items as an update below the initial question rather than editing the initial code you posted, and mark it clearly as an update.)

Comment: I saved the file and restarted my eclipse but the error is still there.
I updated with my AndroidMainfest.xml, please take a look at it.. :)

Comment: @AlfazAhmed I've updated my answer to respond to your updated question. For future reference, an error telling you that you have a duplicate attribute means you should look for something like this -- somewhere where you have the same attribute twice within the same element tag.

Comment: thank you for your help :D, it works now. And thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was the tools:replace duplicated.
Fixed easy:

```
tools:replace="android:label,android:theme">
```

Comment: Thanks! Was searching for so long on how to replace multiple attributes using `tools: replace.` 

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android.name
```

into

```
android:name
```

on the first line...

Answer (score 0):

For instantapp project also check that you have

`xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

in app AndroidManifest.xml in manifest tag.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.start.droidstart"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"   />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_droid" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_droid" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DroidStart"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

instead of

```
<application
    <activity android.name="DroidStart"/>
```

you are using `"android.name"` instead of `"android:name"` for declaring activity in manifest and also close first application tag as `<application>`

Comment: Thank u for looking into my problem :)
I made the changes you suggested. But I am still getting the same error on this line android:name="com.start.droidstart.DisplayMessageActivity"

Comment: @AlfazAhmed : plz add full manifast xml in your question then i will help u more

Comment: I added the full mainfest.xml to my question.
Please take a look at it :)

Comment: see my edit answer and just copy past it in your manifast.xml

Comment: It did solve the problem, but now it gives another error on the very last line "</application>" tag..
it says "error parsing XML: no element found"

Comment: now see my edit answer and check what you are missing in manifest.xml file or copy past it in your manifest.xml

Comment: oops, sorry. I didn't close the manifest tag.
Now it works fine, thank you so much for helping me out :D

Comment: Great!!!!!!:) can you mark it as answer @AlfazAhmed .Thanks so Much if you have any other issue just comment me.

Comment: Thank you for your time :)
I am just starting off with android development, so I'm pretty dodgy with coding now. So any help is lifesaving :D